# Use custom typescript definition in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a file pi.js

```
const Pi = 3.14;
```

With a corresponding pi.d.ts

```
declare const Pi : number;

export = Pi;
```

When I try to import it into my app.component.ts like this

```
import { Pi } from './pi';
```

I get the error message:

> [ts] Module '"e:/code/typescript/lang/src/app/pi"' has no exported
>   member 'Pi'.

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat No I'm not using angular-cli